# Unexpected, exact integer results of floating point operations

Tags: r, floating-point

R produces an exact decimal answer of 1 for 1/3*3. This shouldn't be the case for floating point operations with unavoidable roundoff error:

1/3 ~ 0.(01)
3 ~ 11
1/3 * 3 ~ 0.(1)

Looking at the output from R beyond the limits of double point precision, R computes 1/3*3 as exactly (base-10) 1. How is this result possible when using floating point arithmetic?

```
> sprintf("%.60f",1/3)
[1] "0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125000000"
> sprintf("%.60f",3)
[1] "3.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> sprintf("%.60f",1/3*3)
[1] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: On my machine `0.33333333*3` prints  `1`, but  `0.33333333*3 == 1` is `FALSE`

Comment: `0.3333333333333333*3 == 1` is `TRUE` however (16 decimals instead of 8)

Comment: Why do you think that "it shouldn't be the case"? Note that your justification is using _fixed_ point arithmetic (two bits after the point), not _floating_ point. 1/3 rounded to two bits of precision is 0.011 in binary. Multiply that by 3 (11 in binary) and you get 1.001 in binary, which when rounded to 2 bits gives 1.0.